# -bash: react-native: command not found

Tags: node.js, bash, installation, homebrew, react-native

I have successfully installed brew, node 4.0+, watchman and flow, and I received the following when I do `npm install -g react-native-cli`:

```
/Users/home/.node/bin/react-native -> /Users/home/.node/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
react-native-cli@0.1.5 /Users/home/.node/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli
           └── prompt@0.2.14 (revalidator@0.1.8, pkginfo@0.3.1, read@1.0.7, winston@0.8.3, utile@0.2.1)
```

So I assume `react-native-cli` has been successfully installed as well. However when I run `react-native`, it says:

```
-bash: react-native: command not found
```

My node version is 4.2.1, watchman 3.9, brew 0.9.5 (git 7ed6) and npm 2.14.7

Comment: ***react-native: command not found.*** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189081/react-native-command-not-found

Comment: Others using `nvm` may want to check that their `nvm` version is sustaining. I had this issue when I had old `npm` bin routes in my `PATH` that needed to be removed

Comment: This worked for me, maybe this may be the solution for a similar issue. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24594#issuecomment-486894348

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You have to make sure `/usr/local/share/npm/bin` is in your `PATH` to use binaries installed with `npm`.

Add the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH"
```

And reload your shell session.

---

If you find you don’t have a `/usr/local/share/npm/bin` directory, your `npm` may install its packages in another location. In this case you have to use the right path in the line above.

One solution to find that path is to run:

```
npm list -g | head -n 1
```

This gives you the path where `npm` install its packages. This is not the path you want but it’s close. For example on my Linux it gives `/home/baptiste/.linuxbrew/lib`; it suffices to replace `lib` with `bin` to get the correct path:

```
export PATH="/home/baptiste/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
```

You can use `$HOME` to get your own home directory:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: I've run export PATH="$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH" on the terminal, worked perfect. Thanks!

Comment: there is no `/usr/local/share/npm/bin` path although I had `react-native-cli` installed.

Comment: @zssr I updated my answer to include a way to find the correct directory.

Comment: This solution worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/48638712/1390678

Comment: In my case on Mac 10.13.5, npm list -g | head -n 1 gave result as /usr/local/lib. So I added export PATH="/usr/local/lib:$PATH" to .bash_profile to get this working

Answer (score 22):

I tried many ways to work out a solution to this on my mac(`node -v`: v8.1.3, `npm -v`: 5.0.3). And when I ran `npm install -g react-native-cli`, the output was this:

> /Users/xxx/.npm-packages/bin/react-native -> /Users/xxx/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
>   + react-native-cli@2.0.1
>   updated 1 package in 2.988s

As you can see `react-native` was install in `/Users/xxx/.npm-packages/bin/`, different from what others may say. So I pasted the line `export PATH=/Users/xxx/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH` to my `~/.profile` and opened a new Terminal window to run `react-native`. It worked!

Comment: It works for me, thank you, but is there any document indicating the root reason?

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! It finally works for me!

Comment: Thank you very much brother, I was trying many solutions, but it was not working. This also I tried but enclosed the value with double quote like this (export PATH="/Users/xxx/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"). 

After removing double quote, it worked

Answer (score 11):

First of all, you have to install react native globally

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

then it will show you the path for the react native like the following

```
/Users/{yourUser}/.npm-packages/bin/react-native -> /Users/{yourUser}/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
```

Then you have to set the default path from the above result and execute the following command

```
export PATH="/Users/{yourUser}/.npm-packages/bin/:$PATH"
```

or

```
export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"
```

Then reload you session/env vairables

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

It works for me .... cheers

thanks

Comment: If you are getting Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' issue then try  sudo npm install -g react-native-cli to install the packages

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 .

terminal fire : `npm install -g react-native-cli`

```
output: 

/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.3.0/bin/react-native -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/13.3.0/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
+ react-native-cli@2.0.1
updated 1 package in 4.544s
```

Step 2: export the path

```
  export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.3.0/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy!

Just run `npm i -g react-native-cli` then restart your cmd.

Answer (score 0):

export PATH="$HOME/.npm-`packages`/bin:$PATH" worked for me however, I had to replace packages with what was on my mac.

i.e .npm-`global` instead of .npm-`packages`. ..

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 .

terminal fire : `npm install -g react-native-cli`
output: /usr/local/Cellar/node/6.1.0/libexec/npm/bin/react-native ->/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.1.0/libexec/npm/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.1.0/libexec/npm/lib
└── react-native-cli@0.2.0

Answer (score -4):

```
sudo npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Comment: this and is half right , though you can have a look at correct one ,it also includes env export https://stackoverflow.com/a/48638712/1390678