# React native command not found

Tags: android, ios, node.js, react-native

I am starting to install react native. I had successfully installed homebrew, nodejs , npm. but not able to install react native

First I had tried

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

gives me write warning:

```
Missing write access to /Users/project/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli
```

After that I had tried

```
sudo npm install -g react-native-cli
```

```
/Users/project/.npm-packages/bin/react-native -> /Users/project/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
/Users/project/.npm-packages/lib
└── react-native-cli@1.0.0
```

Looks like install.

After that I tried

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
```

```
Error : react-native: command not found
```

What could be the problem

Comment: as it isn't about programming it would better fit on http://superuser.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react-native: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189081/react-native-command-not-found)

Answer (score 11):

First of all, you have to install react native globally

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

then it will show you the path for the react native like the following

```
/Users/{yourUser}/.npm-packages/bin/react-native -> /Users/{yourUser}/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
```

Then you have to set the default path from the above result and execute the following command

```
export PATH="/Users/{yourUser}/.npm-packages/bin/:$PATH"
```

Then reload you session/env vairables

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

It will work like charm!

Comment: You may want to use `"$HOME/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"` instead; it’ll work with any user home directory.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that `/usr/local/share/npm/bin` is in your PATH to use binaries installed with npm

Add the following line to your ~/.bashrc

`export PATH="/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH"`

Then reload your shell session and try that again

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo yarn global add expo-cli

sudo yarn global add react-native-cli
```

You must use `sudo` here.

Comment: This works for me! I resolved using "sudo yarn global add react-native-cli". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

when you are using the latest version of node js and others related to react native

they updated to run react native app

`npx react-native run-android`
`npx react-native run-ios`

You can check [Here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup#react-native-command-line-interface)