# React Native and Webpack

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I played around with the react native tutorial provided by Facebook. The React Native seemed to have a bundler already. I planned to use Webpack as my bundler and Typescript. How do I use webpack on the current React Native Version?

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45124774/4655003

Comment: Ive tried it and it seemed to not build successfully with the latest version of react-native.

Comment: Looks like the fix is in https://github.com/callstack-io/haul/commit/870753d1df5f2d6f878584adb95a370bc2b5b169 but they have not released a new version for it yet. Probbly just wait a little bit on that, or use React Native 0.45 for now.