# Difference between react-native-init and create-react-native-app

Tags: react-native

What is the Difference between `react-native-init` and `create-react-native-app`.

I'm new to react native.

I've used both command to create new project, with `react-native-init` I get a project with IOS & android project folder & with `create-react-native-app` I get a new project that doesn't has those folders. Which one i should use ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React native vs create react native app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123576/react-native-vs-create-react-native-app)

Answer (score 0):

When we use `create-react-native-app` it will builds a project template based on Expo, a third-party toolkit which allows you to write cross-platform React Native applications using only JavaScript, and provides a smoother workflow for getting the app running on a real device. In addition, Expo provides access to tons of native APIs, for which you'd normally need libraries or custom native code and

When we use `react-native-init` it will creates a plain React Native app template, with native iOS and Android projects you can modify. The downside of this approach is that you'll need to set up the native iOS and Android build chains on your computer, and it's significantly more cumbersome to get started developing and deploying your app.