# Creating new project ReactNative

Tags: react-native

On the official website we can read how to create new project:

> create-react-native-app AwesomeProject

but on tutorials I always see:

> react-native init AwesomeProject

What is the correct? What is the difference between them

Comment: Did you do any research? Googling *"create-react-native-app vs react-native init"* found loads of resources, including a bunch of existing questions here (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/45123576/3001761).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One uses Expo and the other does not. With `create-react-native-app` you use Expo and native code is totally transparent to you.

With the typical `react-native init`, you get all the code and you can modify native code if you want (or write custom native modules).

You can find everything documented here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

First tab, `Quick start` is about `create-react-native-app`, second tab `Building Projects with Native Code` is about `react-native init`.

Probably in most tutorials you find the `react-native init` option because that option is there from the very beginning while `create-react-native-app` is newer new utility.

Recommendation:

1. If you know you will need to modify native code, use `react-native init`. If not, you can go with `create-react-native-app`
2. Even if you go with `create-react-native-app`, if at some point your needs change, you can `eject`

Answer (score 1):

Referencing [EvanBacon's answer](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/516), react native init creates a purely react native app, whereas Facebook's create-react-native-app makes a project "bootstrapped with expo."

Comment: @Jon, there didn't seem to be one on this platform. The link points to Github.

Comment: I summarized what the link said, I did not just link it. Thanks for being safe, though.