# What is the most recommended to start creating a project in React Native?

Tags: react-native

it really confused me what to use between react-native init and create-react-native-app when developing React Native application. Honestly, I don't know where to I start as I'm wondering what should I implement between the two. Does both initialization are the same? I saw in the documentation that create-react-native app is the easiest way to start building a new React Native application. It allows developers to start a project without installing or configuring any tools to build native code - no Xcode or Android Studio installation required. What are the advantages of using react-native init?

Anyway, I'm currently using mac

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React native vs create react native app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123576/react-native-vs-create-react-native-app)

Answer (score 2):

Well, its all depend on your past development platform, 
Like if you are Android or IOS app developer, than my best recommandation is to start with

> react-native-init
>
> so you can manage pod in ios and gradle in android by your self. it
>   will help to create your release .apk and .ipk from your respected
>   Editors.

And if you don't know about app development or either you are fronted or backend developer. than you can try with

> create-react-native-app
>
> In this case you no need to worry about android and ios platform, expo
>   will manage it for you. but there are some limitations. In a long term
>   you'll may need to eject from expo. because there are many library is
>   not supported in expo. you have to use what expo provide.

i developed many small apps on expo, but for big and potential app i whould recommend **react-native-init**

Note*:  it just my opinion, you should check this out before you decide.
[React native vs create react native app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123576/react-native-vs-create-react-native-app)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation and suggestions

Comment: @vidalbenjoe glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

`create-react-native-app` build a expo template,according to [expo](https://expo.io/) Expo is a free and open source toolchain built around React Native to help you build native iOS and Android projects using JavaScript and React.problem is you can only use features that provide by expo [expo docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/create-react-native-app)

but `react-native-init` create project with iOS & android project folder, [according to this guid](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/516) advantage is You can add native modules written in Java/Objective-C check that link for more deatils

if your project build by `create-react-native-app` command you can simply convert by using `npm run eject`