# react-native: command not found

Tags: linux, bash, reactjs, npm, react-native

I am brand new to React native, and following the instructions on the '[getting started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content)' page I came across the following problem. I ran the npm install, however I get `react-native: command not found`. I did `brew install node`, and `brew install watchman` and both installed without errors. Additionally I downloaded xcode from the mac app store earlier today. Any help is appreciated!

Also - I tried the solution on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282545/bash-react-native-command-not-found), however, it still isn't working.

Below is output from the terminal, as well as my .bashrc file located in ~/.

```
Desktop npm install -g react-native-cli
/Users/roni/.npm-global/bin/react-native -> /Users/roni/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
/Users/roni/.npm-global/lib
└── react-native-cli@1.2.0 

 Desktop react-native init reactNativeTest
-bash: react-native: command not found
```

**.bashrc**

```
source /usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh
export PATH="/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH"

### Added by the Bluemix CLI
source /usr/local/Bluemix/bx/bash_autocomplete
```

Please note I changed npm's default directory to another directory, per the npm docs on [fixing npm permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions%5C)

```
Make a directory for global installations:

 mkdir ~/.npm-global
Configure npm to use the new directory path:

 npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
Open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:

 export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
Back on the command line, update your system variables:

 source ~/.profile
```

Comment: did you add `~/.npm-global/bin` to your PATH? What is the output for `echo $PATH`?

Comment: @DTing yes that was it! I added  ~/.npm-global/bin to my .bash_profile and it works. If you reply with an answer I will mark it correct. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Copied down from the comment:**

Add `~/.npm-global/bin` to your PATH, as per the direction:

```
 npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
Open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:

 export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```