# I can't create a react-native project?

Tags: react-native

I installed react native cli and other packages, but can't create a react native project?

> -bash: react-native: command not found

[image: My terminal process screenshot added.]

Comment: You can check the link to solve your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189081/react-native-command-not-found

Answer (score 1):

You have to install react native cli in global. You can use this to do that

```
npm install react-native-cli -g
```

Comment: I was tried but still issues there. react-native command not found.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282545/bash-react-native-command-not-found/33282621 it may help

Comment: it may help you

Comment: I was tried react native older version (react-native init --version="0.42.0" AwesomeProject), working fine.
thank you.

Comment: Unusal! Anyway... Good!

Answer (score 0):

I was having a lot of trouble with this, as none of the other answers provided were working. The top answer here was what allowed me to get through my problem: [npm global path prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803978/npm-global-path-prefix).

If you get a subsequent EACCES permissions problem, use this so as to not having to go back to square one to fiddle with the npm default directory again:

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Comment: when I try the above I get npm not found and I have npm installed