# Cannot run appcenter CLI after successful install

Tags: visual-studio-app-center

I just installed appcenter CLI on my MacBook following this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/cli/

When trying to run the commands from Terminal, e.g. `appcenter login` I get the following error:

`-bash: appcenter: command not found`

I quit all my terminal processes and startet one again, but no luck either. Do I need to export some sort of path for it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anvesh from Appcenter pointed me to this link:
[-bash: react-native: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282545/bash-react-native-command-not-found)
While it is not for appcenter per se, it solved my problem by adding the correct path.

Answer (score 6):

I had similar issue and installing it globally worked

```
npm install -g appcenter-cli
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to install appcenter-cli globally

`yarn global add appcenter-cli`

or using npm

`npm install -g appcenter-cli`

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue ,After running  the installation cmd for appcenter-cli on  successfully and when I have tried to check appcenter version using ***appcenter -v*** cmd on normal command prompt.. it gives me same error:  **appcenter: command not found**
later on when i have tried to run same cmd on ***node.js command prompt then it able to  fetch appcenter details...***